# Pseudo element hover Safari issues

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I really hope someone can help me with this one.

I have a shape that I'd like to have change background color when hovered over it. I've gotten it to work in all browsers, except Safari.

You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bgLv6L9j/5/
I tried using the following code to make the hover work but it cuts off half the text. I tried adding the dimensions of the shape but that also makes it look wonky.

```
.shape:hover::before {
background-color: #245a85;
content: "";
  position:absolute;
  }
```

I've looked through various other topics with the same issue but can't seem to locate any Safari specific problems (or solutions for that matter).

I'd really appreciate it if someone could quickly take a look and see where I'm going wrong with regard to pseudo elements and getting the background hover to work in Safari.

Comment: which version of Safari?

Comment: At the moment, I don't have safari installed. but have you tried just using single colon `:` instead of double colon `::` ?

Comment: I have tried both with one and two colons, neither makes a difference. Thanks for looking though! :)

Comment: @mango I added my answer below, that works on my v6.2.3 let me know if it works for you too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do this:

```
.shape a {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Instead of `relative` It seems that will fix the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/bgLv6L9j/7/

**Edit:**

I rewrote it with a much simple code based on yours.

HTML

```
<a class="shape" href="#">Text</a>
```

CSS

```
.shape {
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 150px;
    height: 75px;
    -moz-transform: perspective(40em) rotatex(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: perspective(40em) rotatex(-45deg);
    -o-transform: perspective(40em) rotatex(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(40em) rotatex(-45deg);
    transform: perspective(40em) rotatex(-45deg);
}

.shape:hover {
    background: crimson;
}
```

That's it. http://jsfiddle.net/8sdqteke/

Comment: Thanks for the help! That does work, but now the text is completely off center. Is there any way to keep the text vertical and horizontally aligned while still setting the position to absolute instead of relative? Thank you!

Comment: You can give some position values to make it look centered, e.g. `left: -40%; top: 40%;`

Comment: Ah yeah, makes sense. However some of the text in the shape is dynamic so it shifts it all over the place. Like so http://jsfiddle.net/bgLv6L9j/11/ Do you know how I could prevent that from happening?

Comment: I rewrote it, see the updated answer above, how does that work for you?

Comment: Thank you for all that! It definitely cuts down on the code a lot which is fantastic! The only thing though is that the text itself seems kind of squished. Would that be fixable by changing the font size or line-height at all?

Comment: unfortunately that is not possible for that simple solution, `perspective` effects apply to all the elements and content inside, and no way to reset.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for trying though, it helped! :) Do you have any ideas how I could do what I was going after? (hover working in safari and centering text inside shape) Maybe some other way of creating the shape?

Comment: Well, the easiest way is using background image, it only takes few minutes to create and works cross browsers.